# Why is Class<?> preferred to Class

Tags: java, generics, raw-types

If I declare a Class as a field:

```
Class fooClass;
```

Eclipse gives me the warning:

> Class is a raw type. References to
>   generic type Class should be
>   parametrized

What does this mean in practice? and why am I urged to do it? If I ask Eclipse for a "quick fix" it gives me:

```
Class<?> fooClass;
```

which doesn't seem to add much value but no longer gives a warning.

EDIT: Why is Class generic? Could you please give an example of parameterization, i.e. could there be a valid use of something other than `<?>` ?

EDIT: WOW! I had not realized the depths of this. I have also watched the Java Puzzler and it's certainly scared me about the bear traps. So I will always use

```
Class<MyString> myStringClass = MyString.class;
```

rather than

```
Class myStringClass = MyString.class;
```

(But having used Java from day one, I didn't really notice when Class became generic);

NOTE: I have accepted @oxbow_lakes as this makes sense to me, but it is clearly a very complicated area. I would urge all programmers to use the specific `Class<MyString>` rather than `Class`. And `Class<?>` is much safer than `Class`.

Comment: Eclipse isn't treating `Class` in a special manner.  That happens when you use any raw type (e.g. `List`).

Answer (score 61, accepted):

### Raw Types and Unbounded Wildcards

None of the previous answers have really addressed why you should prefer `Class<?>` over `Class`, as on the face of it, the former seems to offer no more information than the latter.

The reason is that, the **raw type**, i.e. `Class`, prevents the compiler from making generic type checks. That is, if you use raw types, *you **subvert** the type-system*. For example:

```
public void foo(Class<String> c) { System.out.println(c); }
```

Can be called thusly (it will both compile *and* run):

```
Class r = Integer.class
foo(r); //THIS IS OK (BUT SHOULDN'T BE)
```

But not by:

```
Class<?> w = Integer.class
foo(w); //WILL NOT COMPILE (RIGHTLY SO!)
```

By always using the non-raw form, even when you must use `?` because you cannot know what the type parameter is (or is bounded by), you allow the compiler to reason about the correctness of your program more fully than if you used raw types.

---

### Why have Raw Types at all?

The [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html) says:

> The use of raw types is allowed only as a concession to compatibility of legacy code

You should always avoid them. The unbounded wildcard `?` is probably best described elsewhere but essentially means *"this is parameterized on some type, but I do not know (or care) what it is"*. This is not the same as *raw types*, which are an abomination and do not exist in other languages with generics, like [**Scala**](http://www.scala-lang.org).

---

### Why is Class Parameterized?

Well, here is a use-case. Suppose I have some service interface:

```
public interface FooService
```

And I want to inject an implementation of it, using a system property to define the class to be used.

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName(System.getProperty("foo.service"));
```

I do not know at this point that my class, is of the correct *type*:

```
//next line throws ClassCastException if c is not of a compatible type
Class<? extends FooService> f = c.asSubclass(FooService.class);
```

Now I can instantiate a `FooService`:

```
FooService s = f.newInstance(); //no cast
```

Comment: +1 the only answer so far that actually answers the question!

Comment: @Poindexter - try scala. You'll realize that Java's type system is a bad joke anyway, generics or no generics.

Comment: @oxbow_lakes I totally agree that Java's type system is a joke.  Too bad my job doesn't know that.

Comment: `SomeType` is not the same as `SomeType<?>` (as you note).   It's the same as `SomeType<OtherType>`, where OtherType is the bound of the type parameter (if unspecified, Object).  So `Class` is the same as `Class<Object>`.

Comment: @Mark - that is demonstrably false from my example above! I could not call `foo` with a `Class<Object>` as this would give me a compilation error

Comment: @oxbow: Whoops I didn't mean to imply they were substitutable in a post-generics world.  Your example is an instance where you've only partially introduced generics.  My point was to say how raw types behave.  If, e.g., you wanted to stupidly eliminate all type safety warnings from 1.4 code, you could replace every raw type with its bounds (e.g. `List` with `List<Object>`).  Although as you note you'd get into trouble in these cases.  Sorry for the lack of clarity, I'm having trouble expressing what I mean in a comment :-).

Comment: @Mark - I see. Such a replacement would be both valid and pointless at the same time!

Comment: "raw types [...] do not exist in other languages". Actually, C# does the same, and they are an abomination for compatibility with legacy code in C# as well.

Answer (score 3):

> which doesn't seem to add much value
>   but no longer gives a warning.

You're right. But this might add value:

```
Class<FooClass> fooClass;
```

or, if more appropriate:

```
Class<? extends FooClass> fooClass;
```

or

```
Class<FooInterface> fooClass;
```

As with generics in general, you can improve type safety by specifying *what kind* of class you want the variable to hold. The warning against raw types is just meant to catch pieces of code where this potential is not used. By declaring `Class<?>` you're basically saying "this is *meant* to hold any kind of class".

Comment: The question is about why to prefer an unbounded wildcard over a raw type. I'm not clear that this is an answer

Comment: @oxbow_lakes: I'd say that my last two sentences explain that. Your answer is a lot more thorough in that, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Because, since JDK 5, `Class` has now have parameterized type, which makes `Class` a generic object. This is necessary (since the introduction of Generics) for the compiler to do type checking (at compile time, of course).

`Class<?>` means a "class of unknown" where `?` is a generics [wildcard](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html). It means a that `fooClass` of type `Class<?>` accepts a `Class` whose type matches anything.

Typical example:

```
Class<?> classUnknown = null;
classUnknown = ArrayList.class; //This compiles.
```

You can, effectively, provided a Parameterized Type to be more specific, e.g.:

```
Class<ArrayList> = ArrayList.class;
```

**PS** Bear in mind, that `Class<List> listClass = ArrayList.class;` won't compile (even though ArrayList is of List) but (as Mark Peters mentioned on the comment) `Class<? extends List> listClass = ArrayList.class;` does compile (thanks to the wildcard).

Comment: Your last comment follows from the fact that, in Java, generic types are not *covariant* in their type parameter

Comment: And it's the wildcard that gets around that...`Class<? extends List> clazz = ArrayList.class`.

Answer (score 1):

The Javadoc of the [Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) class does give some idea about why type parameters exist for this class:

> T - the type of the class modeled by
>   this `Class` object. For example, the
>   type of `String.class` is `Class<String>.`
>   Use `Class<?>` if the class being
>   modeled is unknown.

The use of this type parameter is not so obvious, but a cursory look at the source code of the class, indicates why the type parameter is sometimes necessary. Consider the implementation of the `newInstance` method:

```
    public T newInstance() 
        throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
    {
    if (System.getSecurityManager() != null) {
        checkMemberAccess(Member.PUBLIC, ClassLoader.getCallerClassLoader());
    }
    return newInstance0();
    }
```

If one hasn't noticed, the type of the object returned by this method is that of the type parameter. This is useful in code that utilizes a lot of reflection, and where one would like to be extra careful to ensure that objects of the right type are being instantiated.

Considering the example in the question, if the class instance was instead declared as:

```
Class<String> fooClass;
Class<Integer> barClass;
String aString;
```

then, it is next to impossible to have the following code to compile:

```
aString = barClass.newInstance();
```

In short, if you're going to be working with class hierarchies and you wish to impose strict compile time checks to ensure that your code does not need to perform a lot of `instanceof` checks, then you're better off specifying the type of the class that you wish to utilize. Specifying `?` allows all types, but there would be cases when you'll need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Because using raw types instead of parameterized types has many pitfalls.

One of which is that if a raw type is used, all generics on the class are lost. Even those defined per-method.

Comment: "Erased" might be a misleading word...All generics are erased at runtime, raw type or no.

Comment: corrected. But some parametrization information is retained at runtime, not everything is erased ;)