# What are the dangers in upgrading to Java 1.5 and beyond?

Tags: java

I am a long-term user of Java (but I am a scientist and not a professional developer) . I upgrade whenever new versions come out but often I only use a small portion of the new features at first as I don't always have time to study everything.

Recently I learned that unless I fully understood generics I was likely to have serious dangers in using (or in this case not using them) - dangers which I was unaware of and which are not obvious. (I appreciate that I was warned by Eclipse but I didn't understand the warning!)

The particular case in point was that it is now (since 1.5) bad practice to use raw types and that `Class` (rather than `Class<?>` or `Class<MyStuff>`) had serious dangers. see [Why is Class<?> preferred to Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337313/why-is-class-preferred-to-class).

My question is - what others dangers am I likely to encounter and be unaware of as a result of upgrading to Java 1.5 (or 1.6, 1.7) but using my old code or style of programming?

Comment: don't upgrade to 1.5, it's obsolete and no longer supported by sun/oracle.

Comment: @skaffman thanks - I use 1.6 anyway but some of our code comes from others who use 1.5

Comment: Worst problem is that if you ever have to go back to coding in 1.4 or earlier you will start to hate your life.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll speak about the converse (i.e. the benefits):

I'm not aware of dangers (and I've ported Java 1.4 codes to Java 6 without hickups as well as java 5 codes to java 6, java meaning JDK). As for warnings, it's basically a warning (since your code will compile) and you are free to resolve these warnings.

As for as Generics is concerned, Generics are used for Compile-time checking by the compiler, i.e. once the compiler has the element type (e.g. in `Collection`), it can see whether you have used the object correctly with the correct cast.

Generics are implented by *type erasure*. They are present only at compile-time after that the compiler erases it. This is to provide interoperability with legacy codes which uses raw types (e.g. `List` in JDK 1.4).

I don't know if these would be the dangers, but it wouldn't affect your JDK 4 applications:

- Autoboxing
- Enums
- Varargs
- foreach
- Annotations

And you have better performance of the Java Collections Framework.

**PS** the only problem migrating from JDK 1.4 to a new JDK (5 and higher) is you'll face issues with **enum** (as it is a reserved keyword from JDK 5 and higher). OTher than that, you're ok.

Comment: Being picky, the version after Java 1.4 was Java 5.0 followed by Java 6. ;)

Comment: Code that needs to work on J2ME or other non standard profiles, e.g. Skelmir clean room JVM should also avoid 1.5+ features. Both of those would be the exception to the rule though.

Answer (score 3):

I would say benefits from better performance and new features greatly outweigh any "dangers".

The only danger I can foresee is that you'll get a lot of compiler warnings about the very Class/Class you raise. These are more of a nuisance than a danger though.

Comment: The problem identified was that type erasure (in this case fo Class) could cause the program to use different modules and either behave wrongly or crash.

Comment: There are indeed documented issues which can occur with generics, and I can see from your previous posts you're concerned with getting this stuff right. Taking a step back though, I think you're letting potential and reasonably theoretical pitfalls, which I've personally never been hit by in real life, put you off what is actually a safe upgrade. I'd use the motoring metaphor you're preferring a 1998 car  which is past its use-by date because you've heard the SatNav in the 2008 model makes poor recommendations in snowy weather!  Sorry that's more random than I initially thought :-)

Comment: "could cause the program to use different modules" - not really, no; unless you are using a different meaning of the word "module". You are not required to use generics and continuing to use raw types is fine - you just have a lot less certainty about the runtime types of items returned from containers, etc.

Comment: @Brian I agree with you and I am prepared to take risks. It's actually zero cost to avoid this particular problem now so I might as well do it properly. But I agree that I have never been hit by these problems either

Comment: @peter.murray.rust, adding to what matt b said, generics is used only for compilation, i.e. the developer would have to make sure that the element types are used correctly in order for their code to compile. Once compiled, the chances of `ClassCastException` to occur is minimal.

Comment: I agree with Brian. Generics are useful for getting your code correct, but you can safely ignore the warnings (or even switch them off with -warn:none).

Answer (score 3):

Problems we ran into:

- enum is a reserved keyword in java1.5
  (we had to rename some packages).
- External-Jars may depend on java1.4 (weblogic8.2 doesn't run with jdk1.5 we had to upgrade to weblogic9.2)

Consider upgrading your code to use generic-syntax. Depending on your codebase this can be a large project. Using generic-classes and functions is easy. Writing them is more difficult and might force you to refactor your code. 
It's good practice to have few/no warnings in your java-code, so if you don't plan to use generics in your code in short time i would disable the warning, because you might miss a more important warning.

Comment: I suggest just fixing warnings and not to do changes for unecessary "enjoyment" since the OP might break an already working code.

Comment: I have a same scenario i.e., we need to migrate from java1.4 to 1.5 and Weblogic8.1 to Weblogic9.1, I don't want to migrate to higher versions.Can you share some more details of the problems that raised while migration.It would be very helpful if you have any references :).

Answer (score 2):

One thing that breaks with Java5+ JVMs, when migrating from 1.4 code, is the old-style enums.

```
public class Foo {
  public static final INSTANCE1 = new Foo("foo");
  public static final INSTANCE2 = new Foo("bar");
  ...
}
```

Because of the new classloading policy on Java 1.5+ VMs, your "enums" may not be loaded at all, causing NullPointerExceptions.
The solution is obvious : replace them with standart Java5 enums.

Another thing you may consider is the need to train your developers to the new language constructs, mostly generics, enums and the java.util.concurrent stuff.

Aside from this, I tend to think there are only benefits to switching to the most recent JVM version available, both in terms of performance and code quality.

Comment: "Because of the new classloading policy on Java 1.5+ VMs, your "enums" may not be loaded at all" can you provide more information on this? From this sample code, there is nothing wrong about how the instances are declared and a policy change that would cause problems with this would cause lots of other problems with regular-looking code.

Comment: Wow - I had no idea about this issue with Java >1.5, old-style enums, and classloading.  @Olivier - I'd like to understand the issue better.  Got a link to something that explains this in more detail?

Comment: See section §12.4 of the JLS (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.4).
Classes are effectively loaded only if one of a small set of events occur ; merely referencing it is not enough, as seen in the example.

class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                One o = null;
                Two t = new Two();
                System.out.println((Object)o == (Object)t);
        }
}
The class "One" is not loaded here.

A customer of mine had this problem, which is quite hard to diagnose if you don't know the trick !

Comment: The section you linked to wouldn't apply when referring to a 1.4-style enum like `Foo.INSTANCE1`, since you are referring to a static field: *A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the first occurrence of any one of the following... A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant variable*. I'd like to see some more test code that proves this.

Comment: Here is a test case I made which shows there are no problems with 1.4-style enums like this - am I misunderstanding what you've stated? https://gist.github.com/727090

Answer (score 2):

I haven't experienced any issues with upgrading to later versions of Java. The problem I usually face when rebuilding old code with a new compiler version is that Eclipse show a sea of warnings and I feel obliged to fix them.

Generics being a case in point. Collection classes were a mess before generics, but now they're mostly tolerable assuming you fix the warnings. I don't think it's as clean as .NET because generic information doesn't survive to runtime, so it's still possible to break a collection by adding an object of the wrong type. At least with generics the compiler has a chance of catching most errors and generics minimize the amount of casting too. On the flip side, code can get pretty ugly with angle brackets. It's too bad that Java can't infer generic information on occasion. For example it would be nice to be able to say `List<> myList = new ArrayList<String>` and the left side infers its args from the right side.

Likewise, when iterating collections most code goes from one end to the other. It's probably the most common pattern in any code. Therefore it makes sense to have a simplified for loop block which generates all that boiler plate. It doesn't work in every case though, e.g. if you selectively remove elements so there is still the Iterator fallback.

Things like autoboxing are IMO a little more questionable in their application. While it's great that you can cast back and forth between reference and type, I suspect that the risk of comparing inadvertantly comparing references when you meant values or vice versa is much higher. So I would try to minimize or avoid them until you understand the difference between compare by reference and compare by value.

But all these things are opt-in. Unless you use them, your old code should behave the way it did before. The proof is in the pudding of course. Just compile it with JDK 6, see what errors / warnings occur and and see if it runs.

Answer (score 1):

I can understand not going to latest and greatest but Java 5.0 is six years old and has been end of life for over a year. I would suggest going to Java 6, which four years old now.  These versions tried hard to have backward compatilibilty with Java 1.4.  However Java 7, has reduced the backward compatilibity with Java 1.4, so I would suggest migrating to Java 6 before Java 7.